# Not able to perform join in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects, react-typescript

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
var tempObj =  [{
"isAvailable": true,
"receipent": [{
    "id": "a6aedf0c34",
    "receipentName": "ABC"
}, {
    "id": "a6aedbc34",
    "receipentName": "XYZ"
}]  }]
```

And I want name value in a comma-separated string.

I used the below code to achieve this:

```
 var b = Array.prototype.map.call(tempObj.receipent, function (item) {
          return item.receipentName;
        }).join(",");
```

But I am getting the below error:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined**

I also tried this:

```
  var to = tempObj.receipent;
   var b = to.map(e => e.receipentName).join(",");
```

For this I am getting the below error:

**Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Comment: That means `to` object is undefined or null

Comment: `tempObj` is an array with one object as its only element. So `tempObj.receipent` is `undefined` (doesn't exist). `tempObj[0].receipent` exists and is an array. (Side note: When you **already** have an array like `tempObj[0].receipent`, you can just call `map` directly on it, rather than `Array.prototype.map.call`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tempObj` is itself an array. If you just want to process its first element then you have to use `tempObj[0]` and then do as follows

```js
var tempObj =  [{
"isAvailable": true,
"receipent": [{
    "id": "a6aedf0c34",
    "receipentName": "ABC"
}, {
    "id": "a6aedbc34",
    "receipentName": "XYZ"
}]  }];

//tempObj = JSON.parse(tempObj);
var b = tempObj[0].receipent.map(o => o.receipentName).join(",");

console.log(b);

// In case you want to do it for every tempObj then do as follows
tempObj.forEach(obj => {
  const _b = obj.receipent.map(o => o.receipentName).join(",");
  console.log(_b);
});
```